# Bash Evaluation

Tags: bash

I know that in Bash `if` statements can be evaluated with `expr` by using:

```
if [[ 5 > 0 ]]; then echo true; fi
```

How does Bash evaulate the following form of `if`?

```
if [ 5 -gt 0 ]; then echo true; fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one perform a string lexicographic comparison and is `bash` only, while the second perform a numeric comparison and works also in POSIX shell.

The second one could be better written in bash as

```
if ((5 > 0)); then echo "true"; fi
```